# Login to Tiktok using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, tiktok

i'm currently to use the script below to upload tiktok videos, however when running the script im getting hit with the error message "Too many attempts. Try again later." regardless of what login method i use, rotating headers don't seem to fix the error. Any advice?

```html
import time
import random
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager as CM
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

print('=====================================================================================================')
print('Heyy, you have to login manully on tiktok, so the bot will wait you 1 minute for loging in manually!')
print('=====================================================================================================')
time.sleep(8)
print('Running bot now, get ready and login manually...')
time.sleep(4)

bot = uc.Chrome()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
bot = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,  executable_path=CM().install())
bot.set_window_size(1680, 900)

bot.get('https://www.tiktok.com/login')
ActionChains(bot).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys(
    '-').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
ActionChains(bot).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys(
    '-').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
print('Waiting 50s for manual login...')
time.sleep(50)
bot.get('https://www.tiktok.com/upload/?lang=en')
time.sleep(3)


def check_exists_by_xpath(driver, xpath):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False

    return True


def upload(video_path):
    while True:
        file_uploader = bot.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/input')

        file_uploader.send_keys(video_path)

        caption = bot.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/span')

        bot.implicitly_wait(10)
        ActionChains(bot).move_to_element(caption).click(
            caption).perform()
        # ActionChains(bot).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys(
        #     'v').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

        with open(r"caption.txt", "r") as f:
            tags = [line.strip() for line in f]

        for tag in tags:
            ActionChains(bot).send_keys(tag).perform()
            time.sleep(2)
            ActionChains(bot).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()
            time.sleep(1)

        time.sleep(5)
        bot.execute_script("window.scrollTo(150, 300);")
        time.sleep(5)

        post = WebDriverWait(bot, 100).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[5]/button[2]')))

        post.click()
        time.sleep(30)

        if check_exists_by_xpath(bot, '//*[@id="portal-container"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]'):
            reupload = WebDriverWait(bot, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="portal-container"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]')))

            reupload.click()
        else:
            print('Unknown error cooldown')
            while True:
                time.sleep(600)
                post.click()
                time.sleep(15)
                if check_exists_by_xpath(bot, '//*[@id="portal-container"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]'):
                    break

        if check_exists_by_xpath(bot, '//*[@id="portal-container"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]'):
            reupload = WebDriverWait(bot, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="portal-container"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]')))
            reupload.click()

        time.sleep(1)


# ================================================================
# Here is the path of the video that you want to upload in tiktok.
# Plese edit the path because this is different to everyone.
upload(r"C:\Users\redi\Videos\your-video-here.mov")
# ================================================================
```

Anyone have a workaround the Tiktok block?

Answer (score 2):

While attempting to login, re-login or creating an account ***TikTok*** platform may even wrongly identify you as a bot or spam and for the next 5 minutes or so, you may keep getting the *Too many attempts. Try again later.* error message when trying to sign in to TikTok as follows.

[image: TikTok_Too many attempts_Try again later]

To avoid getting detected as a bot you can use your default user login profile and you can use the following solution:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

# Chrome is controlled by automated test software
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

# avoiding detection
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

# Default User Profile
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")

bot = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,  executable_path=CM().install())
bot.get('https://www.tiktok.com/login')
```

Comment: I tried implementing this code but still receiving same error and unable to login in regardless of method

Comment: Yeah sadly even when you login manually and then use the Default profile in selenium, seems that Tiktok somehow detects that and logs you out :( 
Thanks for useful options though, didn't know of them!

Comment: update: in addition to your instructions what worked for me was using selenium-stealth https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth#usage

Answer (score 0):

Remarks to @karlicoss

Use stealth browser initialized using

```
from selenium_stealth import stealth  # noqa
stealth(self.driver, platform='Win32', fix_hairline=True)
```

This worked for me